# How to handle browser notification popup which is without any elements?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

How to press the `OK` button as per the image.
I can switch to this window. but it is not loaded till i click ok, so there is no any elements.
Alert handle does't helped too.
Autoit cannot detect this pop up message too.
disable-notifications cant help too.
Any ideas?
Two screeshots is added.

Firefox snapshot:

[image: Look from FF]

Chrome Snapshot:

[image: Look from Chrome]

```
p.companieGenreal.sActivities().click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
p.companieGenreal.sAddNew().click();
p.companieGenreal.sAddJobOrder().click();
p.companieGenreal.sContract().click();      
swithToChildWindow(parent);
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: I can switch to this window. How did you do that ?

Comment: Did you try writing `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()`

Comment: This is java script alert and can be easily handled by selenium. I think the problem is with timing, you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until alert present as `new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).accept()`..Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

To treat it as an alert try this:

```
 Alert a = driver.switchTo().alert();
 a.confirm();
```

If it can be closed with Escape key, send Escape keypress like this (or **ENTER** if it closes when Enter is hit):

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```

Comment: Thanks!
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE); is helped!

Answer (score 1):

### beforeunload

The [**`beforeunload`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event is fired when the window, the document and its resources are about to be unloaded. At this point of time the document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

**Note**: Since 25 May 2011, the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#user-prompts) states that calls to [`window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), [`window.confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm), and [`window.prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) methods may be ignored during this event.

### Solution

There are multiple ways to disable this popup as follows:

- Firefox: If you are using *Firefox* as your *Browser Client* you can use an instance of `FirefoxOptions()` and set the preference **`dom.disable_beforeunload`** to **`true`** as follows:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  FirefoxOptions firefox_option = new FirefoxOptions();
  firefox_option.addPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true);
  WebDriver firefox_driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefox_option);
  firefox_driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
  ```
- Chrome: If you are using *Chrome* as your *Browser Client* you can use an instance of `ChromeOptions()` and add the argument **`--disable-popup-blocking`** as follows:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions chrome_option = new ChromeOptions();
  chrome_option.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
  chrome_option.addArguments("start-maximized");
  chrome_option.addArguments("disable-infobars");
  WebDriver chrome_driver = new ChromeDriver(chrome_option);
  chrome_driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If that is an alert you could handle using below methods:

1. driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
2. `"Actions class"`:

   ```
    Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
    builder.sendKeys(keys.ESCAPE);
   ```
3. if the above two methods didn't work then there is a special alert type called "sweet alert" which can be inspected and write code for that.

Answer (score 0):

try using this :

```
 public static void acceptAlertUsingJs(WebDriver driver) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.alert = function(msg){return true;};");  
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.prompt = function(msg) { return true; }");        
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code and see if it helps:

```
if (isAlertPresent()){           
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                }       
    }   
        public static boolean isAlertPresent() {
        try {
         driver.switchTo().alert(); 
         Thread.sleep(5000);
        return true;
        }// try
        catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
        }// catch
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same kind of issue a modal pop up window opens to which i am able to switch to  and [image: Sample Image]click the OK button but cannot fetch the text present in it. The modal dialog is shared in the screenshot and has no html tags hence i cannot locate the text in it using any locator. I tried using driver.switchTo().alert().getText() to fetch the text present in it.