# How to disable the "Are you sure you want to leave this page" alert?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using c # selenium webdriver. I want to turn off chrome warnings. For example, disable the are you sure to leave this page alert. None of the codes below worked. You can help with the explanatory code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
    options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions"); // to disable extension
    options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications"); // to disable notification
    options.AddArguments("--disable-application-cache"); // to disable cache
    options.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
    options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
    options.AddArgument("--incognito");
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
    driveri = new ChromeDriver(options); 
    driveri.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://web.com");

    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driveri; 
    js.ExecuteScript("window.alert = function() {};");
}
```

Comment: There is no Chrome setting which will stop this, the only options are adding a Chrome plug-in called `GreaseMonkey` and running some script, definitely not ideal, or override the `onbeforeunload` event in your own custom script, by using the JavascriptExecutor of Selenium (https://superuser.com/questions/593116/how-to-prevent-javascript-alerts-that-fire-when-leaving-a-page)

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555208/how-to-handle-browser-notification-popup-which-is-without-any-elements

Answer (score 3):

Hi I solved my problem with the Let Me Out named chrome extensions. Maybe it's what he needs. Below my sample code.

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
 options.AddExtensions(@"C:\Let-Me-Out_v1.3.crx");
 driveri = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: @"C:\Let-Me-Out_v1.3.crx" do i need to place this in the path and what is the python code for the same.

Comment: It does not look like a clean solution ,you should explain why you have put C:Let-me_Out_V1.3.crx.... Any clean solution for python