# Python and Selenium - Python waits for alert to close before it continues to run

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Using Python 3+ and Selenium > IE Driver.

I am running a python script to automate the setup of a user on system as there isn't any other way then using the webpage.

The problem that I am having is when I try to navigate away from a page if the user is a duplicate, I am getting a JS alert asking me if I am sure I want to leave the page because of unsaved data.

I have tried the below code.

```
alert = browser.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
```

Python seems to stop and doesn't continue to interact with the browser till the JS alert has been cleared. For example the Python window will display the flashing busy indicator like its doing something in till I select "OK" on the alert. Once this has been done the code will continue to run and return a Alert exception because the alert is no longer there proving that the script is waiting for the alert to be handled before continuing.

If anyone could add to this or point me in the right direction I would be greatly appreciated.

[Alert Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRzsE.png)

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of that alert ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I have added the picture at the bottom of my post, it would seem to be just a standard alert. Thanks for taking your time to help me with this.

Comment: No, that's a browser based alert, selenium can't help you to handle that.

Comment: @cruisepandey I don't suppose you know a work around? I thought you can handle the browser alerts, you can on firefox etc?

Comment: yes, can be done using 3rd party tools like AutoIT , or robot class in case of JAVA. Since the OP is about python and JS so not really sure.

Comment: you can check this , we had one ticket recently : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619300/how-to-disable-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-leave-this-page-alert

Comment: @cruisepandey thanks any way. I am probably going to adjust my script so I check for that user before I enter the form.