# How to prevent popping-up xdg-open dialogue from Ubuntu chrome while opening specific link?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to join a whatsapp group using desktop web whatsapp (chrome, ubuntu). When I click on Join Group, It shows dialogue below.I want to remove this dialogue forever from chrome. I can join the group by clicking again on join the group after dismissing the xdg-open dialogue.

I tried [Reset chrome protocol_handler chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465586/how-to-reset-external-protocol-handler-in-chrome) with no luck.

I also tried to dismiss the dialogue using python selenium with no luck using below code.

```
               try:

                    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                           'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                           'confirmation popup to appear.')
                    #if it doe
                    alert = browser.switch_to.alert()
                    alert.accept()
                    print "alert accepted"
                except TimeoutException:
                    print "no alert"
                    pass
```

Is there a way to dismiss the dialogue using python selenium or using some configuration file changes in chrome installation ?

[image]

Comment: Did you tyr https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400934/handle-notifications-in-python-selenium-chrome-webdriver ?

Comment: Just tried. No luck :(

Comment: Checkout this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555208/how-to-handle-browser-notification-popup-which-is-without-any-elements

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: This worked for me. https://community.shotgunsoftware.com/t/how-to-fix-chrome-protocol-handler-always-open-these-types-of-links-pop-up-when-opening-rv-through-rvlink/4306

Answer (score 7):

This solution works on Google Chrome 84.0.4147.89, for specific types of xdg links. For example, if the link in question is `whatsapp://someurl`, you can use:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/ && echo '{ "URLWhitelist": ["whatsapp://*"] }' |sudo tee /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/whitelist.json
```

Comment: UPD: they renamed `URLWhitelist`/`whitelist.json` to `URLAllowlist`/`allowlist.json`, and the same for blacklist→blocklist.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the official documentation (https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532419) on how to do it.

@Eyal's answer is pretty close. Instead you should set the `URLBlocklist` field.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed
cd /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed
jq -n '.URLBlocklist=["whatsapp://*"]' | sudo tee blocklist.json
```

Comment: “ssh” links are blocked - wtf? the question was "how to remove poup" without blocking app.

Answer (score 1):

This worked out for me...
go to  .local/share/applications/
create a **file** .. say **whatsapp.desktop** with the following info

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Whatsapp Scheme Handler
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %u
StartupNotify=false
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/whatsapp;
```

then registry the scheme handler  with the following command

```
     xdg-mime default whatsapp.desktop x-scheme-handler/whatsapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a hack. Retrieve the link element of the "Continue to chat" button and open the URL in the href attribute.

Comment: this is a selenium question. you can open and operate devtools with selenium?

Comment: @starball you can get the html element and read the href attribute?