# Selenium dismiss open external application confirmation alert

Tags: node.js, selenium, google-chrome

I am writing a selenium (node) test that hits a page which attempts to launch an external application.

When the page wants to launch the external app, a dialog appears in chrome which offers the user the chance to "Open" the other application or "Cancel." I want my selenium script to dismiss this box, in other words to click the cancel button.

This external app opening confirmation box doesn't appear to act like a normal "Alert" since the following has not worked:

```
await driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys(webdriver.Key.ENTER) //since the cancel button is focused by default
```

and

```
await driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss()
```

Is there a way to dismiss this dialog with selenium?

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I am also facing similar problem.

Comment: No I ended up closing the current tab and opening a new one. This happened to work based on the structure of my app.

Comment: I found a solution after doing some research. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986354/how-to-prevent-popping-up-xdg-open-dialogue-from-ubuntu-chrome-while-opening-spe#answer-64538468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium cannot handle Browser prompts. It cannot only interact with the DOM of the page.

Comment: This prompt locks up the page, and prevents further interaction with the DOM. Does that mean its impossible to proceed with the test?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any solution to get rid of this message but as a workaround you can open the website that prompts this message and switch to another tab.

Chrome on Windows will only show this message at one tab so your second tab should be free to use. I guess this works the same on other browsers and OS.