# handle popups in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am currently working on a project where I am automating whatsapp messages through url. like this [https://wa.me/number_here](https://wa.me/12345)

whenever i do it normally everything goes fine, but when I try to automate this a whatsapp popup box appears and blocks everything, I mean everything, no right-click no developer options, that is why i cant get the x path of the button on that popup. i have tried (driver.shift_to,alert.close)but it says that there is no such alert. i have tried to find the button by contains(text) method but also did not work. here is my code.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir = user-data') 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])  
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')      
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path= driver_path)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
contact = f'https://wa.me/{number}'        

    driver.get(contact)      
    time.sleep(3)

    alert = wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alert.accept()
```

[image]

please help me how to bypass this popup. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this link can be helpful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19019311/12000849

> What I do is to set a conditional delay with WebDriverWait just before the point I expect to see the alert, then switch to it, like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("url")
browser.find_element_by_id("add_button").click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                   'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                                   'confirmation popup to appear.')

    alert = browser.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    print("alert accepted")
except TimeoutException:
    print("no alert")
```

Comment: thank you brother I tried this, it gives the message but popup is still there

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for PA creation confirmation popup to appear.

Comment: @Romeo Did you try to set a bigger timeout? Not 3, but 30 e.g.

Comment: shift_to.alert does not work here, it is a different type of box, It blocks  mouse click outside of the box. you can only click on the check box and on the buttons available on the popup, you can not click anywhere else

Comment: yes i have tried 10 sec also although popup appears immediately

Comment: @Romeo As I read now, with 99% we can't move to this popup via selenium...(

Comment: please man, its the last hope, actually i am trying to start a new chat through whatsapp web. we can continue messaging if we have have conversation with some one. but what if i want to start chat with 500 new people without saving their number into contact list. i mean this is the only way if we can bypass that popup

Comment: @Romeo try maybe this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62942891/12000849

Comment: it works dear thanks...... i will try it on windows too
thank you very much